# Is there a better way to check if all elements in a list are named?

Tags: r

I want to check if all elements in a list are named. I've came up with this solution, but I wanted to know if there is a more elegant way to check this.

```r
x <- list(a = 1, b = 2)
y <- list(1, b = 2)
z <- list (1, 2)

any(stringr::str_length(methods::allNames(x)) == 0L) # FALSE, all elements are
                                                     # named.

any(stringr::str_length(methods::allNames(y)) == 0L) # TRUE, at least one
                                                     # element is  not named.
                                                     # Throw an error here.

any(stringr::str_length(methods::allNames(z)) == 0L) # TRUE, at least one
                                                     # element is  not named.
                                                     # Throw an error here.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if the following base R code works for your general cases, but it seems work for the ones in your post.

Define a function `f` to check the names

```
f <- function(lst) length(lst) == sum(names(lst) != "",na.rm = TRUE)
```

and you will see

```
> f(x)
[1] TRUE

> f(y)
[1] FALSE

> f(z)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: That does not work in case of a name being `NA`: `y <- as.list(1:26); names(y) <- c(LETTERS[1:25])`. In that case `f(y)` returns `NA` when we want `FALSE`.

Comment: Great! Not only does your solution capture NAs, it is even fast.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a function to check if the the `names` attribute is `NULL` or (`|`) there is blank (`""`) name, negate (`!`)

```
f1 <- function(lst1) is.list(lst1) && !(is.null(names(lst1))| '' %in% names(lst1))
```

-checking

```
f1(x)
#[1] TRUE
f1(y)
#[1] FALSE
f1(z)
#[1] FALSE
```

---

Or with `allNames`

```
f2 <- function(lst1) is.list(lst1) && !("" %in% allNames(lst1))
```

-checking

```
f2(x)
#[1] TRUE
f2(y)
#[1] FALSE
f2(z)
#[1] FALSE
```